# Custom equality comparer for `BinaryFormatter`

Tags: c#, binaryformatter, binary-serialization

##### TL;DR;

My custom `[Serializable]` class overrides `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, so multiple distinct objects can be "equal", and it looks like `BinaryFormatter` calls `OnSerialized` only once, but calls `OnDeserialized` twice when two equal but distinct (`ReferenceEquals` == `false`) objects exist in the graph.

What can I do to ensure that for every call to `[OnSerialized]` method `[OnDeserialized]` method is called exactly once provided I want to keep my `GetHashCode` and `Equals` implementations?

Ideally, I would like to instruct `BinaryFormatter` to use my custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer` for my custom class so that it would not try to "merge" distinct but equal instances.

##### Background

The class wraps a refcounted unmanaged handle, that is passed across app domains using `BinaryFormatter`. To keep the refcount in sync with alive .NET instances, I increase it by 1 in `[OnSerialized]` handler, assuming the object will be deserialized exactly once, which is violated in the scenario above (the serialized bits are discarded after deserialization).

Comment: I don't think it would make sense for `[OnDeseriaized]` to only be called once. You need the deserialized object to use `GetHashCode` and `Equals.` This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) anyway. Specifially: why are you using `BinaryFormatter` for this? Could you show some code to give a better picture?

Comment: Have you looked at the `BinaryFormatter` docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-6.0, particularly this part: _"Warning BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure."_

Comment: @Flydog57 the security issues of `BinaryFormatter` are irrelevant in my case, because my lib only deserializes what it serialized previously.

Comment: @Llama I anticipated the XY thing by mentioning my use case in the background section: I need to preserve class instances that wrap unmanaged resources, and have custom implementations of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` across app domains. In particular, for Unity editor.

Comment: Well, can you provide some code (a [mcve])?

Comment: @Llama I doubt it will help, but here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/lostmsu/a4268ed09af2e87de9999f8abbbd997e

Comment: BTW, related question with a very similar problem from 2012 (!) https://stackoverflow.com/a/11462811/231238

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `ISerializable` instead of using `[OnSerialized]` attribute works: `GetObjectData` gets called for each distinct object even if they are equal by `Equals` + `GetHashCode`.

Downsides are:

1. It is probably slower
2. Now all types deriving from the wrapper must have a deserializing constructor with signature `.ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)`